# Dynamically generated jbuttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a GUI for that simulates elevators in a building (really to test threading/c-scan), but when generating the buttons for the elevator control panel and the buttons for each individual floor, I'm kind of stuck. I thinking about trying to generate a new pair of buttons for each floor, and generating a new control panel per elevator. Also there's the difficulty of having a variable amount of floors. Anyway my question what is this best way to go about doing this? Perhaps it's not necessary to generate new buttons for everything and just use one set and change what the actions do per floor/elevator? I'm asking because I'm not very familiar with GUIs. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the elevators, and the control panel are the same, you can use a singular method and pass in the elevator or the control panel. CustomPanel extends JPanel and has a method foo.

```
public void createElevatorButtons(final CustomPanel panel) {
    ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>(); //arraylist of buttons we can keep track of
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); //the visible component
    for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfFloors;i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(i)); //creates buttons for floors 1 to max
        buttons.add(button);
        buttonPanel.add(button);
    }
    panel.add(buttonPanel);

    //add the action listeners
    for(JButton button : buttons) {
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton floor = (JButton) e.getSource();
                int floorNumber = Integer.parseInt(floor.getText());
                panel.foo(floorNumber); //we tell the elevator/panel/whatever to do something, you will have to extend JPanel to do foo
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case that the number of floors is variable you can create an array of buttons:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[MAX_NUMBER_OF_FLOORS];
```

Then when you determine the exact of number of floors at runtime, you can go to instantiate and add the buttons:

```
for(int i=0; i<numberOfFloors; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    controlPanel.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

Something like this should work.

Assign MAX_NUMBER_OF_FLOORS a big number like 100, there should be a possible limit given by the problem.